# preg match (): range out of order

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a string that contains only Cyrillic letters so I try this:

```
<?php  
$pattern="#[x\{0410}-x\{042F}]#u";  
$string="АФ";  
echo preg_match ($pattern,$string);  
?>
```

But I get this error

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 10 in /home/ge0rgi/www/preg.php on line 4

Comment: Try backslash in front of x... `\x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern= "#[\x{0410}-\x{042F}]#u";
```

Returns 1 but doesn't match F...

```
Array
(
    [0] => А
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you have not opened '{' statement. because before it you have slash. that's why there is undefined ending at 10 and 19 chars